Array in tblr Environment
I am wondering if there is a better way to align my equation in my tblr environment. I don't like the spacing, and I can't seem to figure out another way to clean it up.

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[headsep=2in]{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=0.25in,            % <-- you want to adjust this
  inner=0.5in,
  outer=0.5in,
  bottom=0.5in,
  headheight=3ex,   
  }    % <-- and this

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,tasks,ragged2e,tasks} % Math packages
\usepackage{multicol,parskip,graphicx,fancyhdr,tikz,pgfplots,tabularray}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\NewDocumentCommand{\topic}{mm}{\bfseries{Topics #1: }{#2}}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\lhead{\textbf{Skill Builder: } Topic 3.2: Implicit Differentiation}
\chead{}
\rhead{Name: \hspace{5cm}}

\fancyfoot[L]{Created By: Mr. Bennett} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{Implicit Differentiation} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{25pt}

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{.25in}
    
    \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,colspec={XX},rows={3.5in},rows={valign=h},row{1}={0in}}
        \SetCell[c=2]{l} 2.  Find \(\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\) for each equation below. \\
            a). \(x^3-y^3=7\)   &   b). \(3xy-4\cos x=-6\) \\
            
        \SetCell[c=2]{l} 3.  Given \(e^{y}+xy=4\), describe and correct the error in finding \(dy/dx\).
            \vspace{.5in}
        
        \(\begin{array} {cl} \dfrac{d}{dx}\left[e^{y}+xy\right] & = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left[4\right] \\[.15in] e^{y}+x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y & = 0 \\[.15in] x\dfrac{dy}{dx} & = -e^{y}-y \\[.15in]  \dfrac{dy}{dx}& =  \dfrac{-e^{y}-y}{x} \end{array}\)
    \end{tblr}

        
\end{document}



Have you tried the aligned environment? It does the same as align but in a inline math.

Hi Alain, I read that you could not used the aligned environment within tables. I had tried previously on another note packet but it did not work.

I'd use aligned and not try to align the equals signs.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[headsep=2in]{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=0.25in,
  inner=0.5in,
  outer=0.5in,
  bottom=0.5in,
  headheight=3ex,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,tasks,ragged2e,tasks} % Math packages
\usepackage{multicol,parskip,graphicx,fancyhdr,tikz,pgfplots,tabularray}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\NewDocumentCommand{\topic}{mm}{\textbf{Topics #1: }{#2}}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\lhead{\textbf{Skill Builder: } Topic 3.2: Implicit Differentiation}
\chead{}
\rhead{Name: \hspace{5cm}}

\fancyfoot[L]{Created By: Mr. Bennett} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{Implicit Differentiation} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{25pt}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines,
  vlines,
  colspec={XX},
  rows={3.5in},
  rows={valign=h},
  row{1}={0in}
}
\SetCell[c=2]{l} 2.  Find \(\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\) for each equation below. \\
a). \(x^3-y^3=7\)   &   b). \(3xy-4\cos x=-6\) \\
            
\SetCell[c=2]{l} 3.  Given \(e^{y}+xy=4\), describe and correct the error in finding \(dy/dx\).

\medskip

\(\begin{aligned}
&  \frac{d}{dx}[e^{y}+xy] = \frac{d}{dx}[4] \\
&  e^{y}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+y = 0 \\
&  x\frac{dy}{dx}         = -e^{y}-y \\
&  \frac{dy}{dx}          = \frac{-e^{y}-y}{x}
\end{aligned}\)
\end{tblr}
     
\end{document}

I commented out fullpage and changed the keys to geometry: both packages act on the same thing, so either one or the other. The latter is much more flexible.
I also removed the useless \left and \right commands.

